# Read UPPERCASED Env Variables to PascalCased properties using ConfigurationBuilder

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, configuration, environment-variables

My application reads some config data from environment variables on initialisation and stores this data in a configuration object, using `ConfigurationBuilder` and the `Configure<TOptions>` method.

My problem is that these environment variables are UPPERCASED (and snake_cased) like:

```
MY_FIRST_VAR=1
MY_SECOND_VAR="Two"
```

I wanted to have my TOptions object as:

```
public int MyFirstVar { get; set; }
public int MySecondVar { get; set; }
```

but them the object does not get filled by the startup. It does work when I create it as:

```
public int MY_FIRST_VAR { get; set; }
public int MY_SECOND_VAR { get; set; }
```

but then the naming sucks...

I know it is sort of a first world problem, but is there a way I can use the first naming format and make it work? :)

> P.S.: I can't change the environment variable names, they are used by other processes

Comment: you can use AutoMapper

Comment: You can write your  own `EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider` and replace it with yours. [Source](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/master/src/Config.EnvironmentVariables/EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider.cs) might be outdated.

Comment: Both seem like overkill for my scenario. I was really hoping for some configuration based solution.